# Access results from FQL statement using Facebook C Sharp SDK

Tags: dynamic, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I have this FQL statement:

```
 var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic result = fb.Get("fql",
            new { q = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0" });
```

Now I am trying to access each individual column like this:

```
dynamic a = result.post_id;
```

However, it's returning null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

FQL returns the data inside the property "data"... and that property is an array.... so... to get the whole collection you need:

```
var rows = result.data;
```

to get the 'post_id' of the first row:

```
var post_id = result.data[0].post_id;
```

So... If you want to show the list of 'post_id'... you could:

```
foreach (var item in result.data)
{
    Response.Write(item.post_id);
}
```

Hope that helps!